# Is there a function in dearpygui that extracts the exact selection from a text input widget?

Tags: python, dearpygui

So i have this app that consists of a text area and a button. I can edit the text text Area, select the exact text with mouse and click the button that extracts the text and processes it.

Here's a snip using tkinter library -

```
textEdit = scrolledtext.ScrolledText ( master = self.root) # declaration
..... 
str_text = textEdit.selection_get()  ##extracting the exact text that's selected
```

With dearpy gui , I have below code snip.

```
textEdit = dpg.add_input_text(tag= 'textEdit',multiline= True)   #declaration
.....
str_text = dpg.get_value ('textEdit')    #extracting the exact text that's selected
```

The only problem is it doesn't give the selection, rather the whole text inside the text area. Is there any trick that can help my problem?

Comment: Typo error `str_text = textEdit. selection_get()` Should be `str_text = textEdit.selection_get()`